# React Native - deny ANY fetch calls to be made, iOS app - it's NOT because of HTTP

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I am currently trying to make an app, but I am are having issues trying to fetch a token from the server.

The server is on my local machine using ngrok as proxy, so it's basically an HTTPS request, even though I have added in infoPlist to allow insecure HTTP calls.

The only error I get is this!!!

```
Network Error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:183:16 in createError
* null:null in handleError
- node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2370:26 in dispatchEvent
- node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:1885:9 in setReadyState
- ... 7 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I have tried to go into folder *node_modules* and *console.log* the error, but this is what I get.

```
Network Error null Object {
  "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
  "data": "{\"method\":\"POST\",\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"},\"data\":\"{\\\"username\\\":\\\"Wwqes\\\",\\\"password\\\":\\\"Adasd\\\"}\"}",
  "headers": Object {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  },
  "maxContentLength": -1,
  "method": "post",
  "timeout": 0,
  "transformRequest": Array [
    [Function transformRequest],
  ],
  "transformResponse": Array [
    [Function transformResponse],
  ],
  "url": "undefined/auth/login",
  "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
} undefined
```

The *actual* fetch call. I am using [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to fetch.

```js
    const fetchOptions: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })
    };
    return await axios.post(url, fetchOptions)
        .then((response) => { console.log(response); return response })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error); return error });
}
```

I know with full certainty that the call is not being sent to the server, nor going out. It's somehow being caught from the app itself. **I have also tried with a normal fetch**, but still it doesn't work.

What is the solution?

Comment: Can you try your post in postman?

Comment: yes i have tried it and it works

Comment: Can you post it

Comment: https://3a36a79b.ngrok.io
its working fine, i have checked

Comment: I cannot see the link. Can you post screenshot of postman.

Comment: its the one that you clicked on, i am just using ngrok for proxy, so it will show as https instead of http. i know it works because you clicked on it acouple of times :D

Comment: i am running my server on localhost that why i cant really give you the correct url

Comment: It's valid https if not is a problem.

Comment: Please provide screenshot of postman window.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/m7DSyUO
that the exact same url that i have up there

Comment: Can you post your localhost url?

Comment: i mean why would you want that, im not trying to be rude but its completely different thing ?

Comment: Console.log  your url according to error you have url": "undefined/auth/login",

Comment: May be you did not set right url value

Comment: but how you knooowww, You were completely right YOU ARE AMAZING.

Comment: Did you check what I wrote?

Comment: How can i mark it the right answer =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Console.log* your URL according to the error you have:

> url: "undefined/auth/login",

You have an undefined value in the URL string.

Comment: How is "Console.log" a verb? What does it mean? Just looking/search in file "Console.log"? Running some executable? Calling function *Console.log()* (in what context?)? Or something else?